# validate and save in django field

Tags: python, django, validation

I have written a function that accept as input a string and do some validation tasks on it and also changes the value.

```
def validate(str):
    # do validation. If any error, raise Validation error
    # modify value of str
    return str
```

I want to use this function as a validator for some django model field. I know how to do it. My problem is that in addition to validation I want the modified value, i.e. return value of function, to be saved in field.

Comment: You can assign model value like this `row=Lab(ip=IPpool[i])
row.pingstatus=ispingable(IPpool[i])` here lab is model . first line is to instantiate and second line to assign function return value to a model column . ispingable is function here . Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I want it in django

Comment: in models.py file ?

Comment: yes in django fields

Comment: in django models.py file , we will declare field data type , length ,is it a primary key and default value . So you want to make the return value of function as default value of model field ? Can you give some example ?

Answer (score 1):

The **models.py** module is not right place to do this as input validation is usually done in forms. But still you can do it in **Model.save()** method:

```
# models.py

def validate(str):
    # do validation. If any error, raise Validation error
    # modify value of str
    return str


class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    field_to_validate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.field_to_validate = validate(self.field_to_validate)
        except YourValidationError:
            self.field_to_validate = ''
        super(YourModel, self).save(**kwargs)
```